# Batch file won't run correctly with windows task scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file which will perform the below actions

- convert a example.csv file encoding from `ansi` to `utf8` encoding
- compress the example.csv file and move the contents to zip file example.zip folder. example.csv will no longer be available in the path
- transfer the zip folder example.zip to sftp server.

When I run the batch file manually (double click the batch file) the above actions perform well and as expected.

When I run the batch file via task scheduler,

- utf8 encoding is happening properly
- the 22bytes example.zip file is transferring to sftp server. it doesnt have the file example.csv in the file example.zip when I extract it.

anybody have ideas to troubleshoot the issue? thank you

Batch file content is below:

```
@echo off

PowerShell.exe -Command "& 'D:\PeopleData\META\Scripts\encode_to_utf8.ps1'"

echo The program will wait 20 seconds before continuting, interrupted by the user
timeout /t 20

cscript.exe D:\PeopleData\META\Scripts\compress_csv.vbs"

echo The program will wait 100 seconds before continuting, interrupted by the user
timeout /t 100

START D:\PROGRA~2\WinSCP\winscp.exe /console /script=D:\PeopleData\META\Scripts\Itsm_to_sftp.txt

Exit
```

Comment: Do any of your scripts use relative paths to create or read the example.csv, example.zip files? The problem may be in either the .ps1 or the .vbs. If the scripts don't specify a fully-qualified-path, then the file gets created into or read from the current directory, which can be different when you run manually vs scheduled.

Comment: Insert below `@echo off` either `cd /D "%~dp0"` or `pushd "%~dp0"` to make the directory of the batch file the current directory like when you double click on the batch file. The current directory set by Windows task scheduler is `%SystemRoot%\System32`.